# Do the options LegendFunction->"Frame" and PointSize work?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, options

1. In the Mma versions up to 12.2 the function `LegendFunction->"Frame"` worked. Now (version 13.2, Win.10) it seems not to work:

   `ListPlot[{Range[5], Range[5]^2}, Frame -> True,  PlotLegends ->  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["First", 12], Style["Second", 12]},  LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.2, 0.8}]]]`

[image]

This is also true in the StyleSheet->JournalArticle.

**Did I miss something?**

2. In the StyleSheet->JournalArticle, the option `PointSize` seems not to function:

`ListPlot[{Range[5], Range[5]^2},  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.03], PointSize[0.1]}]`

[image]

**Did I miss something in this case?**

Comment: In version `13.2.0` on a mac it works properly; see the [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkOsg.png)

Comment: Does this work: `LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &)`

Comment: @Syed  Yes, this works.

Comment: 13.2 Windows 10. `LegendFunction -> Framed` instead of  `LegendFunction->"Frame` works

Comment: @Daniel Huber Thank you.